# Ho to use contains function in DynamoDB with DynamoDBMapper Java?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, dynamodb-mapper

I need to check list of data with `contains` function is DynamoDB. Following is my Java Code,

```
List<String> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
```

I am inserting the above list inside a JSON called Data.

```
Map<String, AttributeValue> valueMap = new HashMap<>();
valueMap.put(":v", new AttributeValue().withS(String.valueOf(dataList)));

Map<String, String> nameMap = new HashMap<>();
nameMap.put("#list", "Data.list");

DynamoDBQueryExpression<> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<>()
                .withFilterExpression("contains(#list, :v)")
                .withExpressionAttributeNames(nameMap)
                .withExpressionAttributeValues(valueMap)
                .withConsistentRead(false);
```

I used the above approach but it is not working. What I need is I need to filter data if any of the list values contains in the dynamo db inserted list values. The list data is inside Json. So what I am doing wrong here? can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your query doesn't has the `withKeyConditionExpression` as part of building `DynamoDBQueryExpression`.
2. `FilterExpression` is not improving your RCUs consumption. It adds very little value. I prefer having clean query objects ( `ddbMapper.query(Object)` ) and filtering post getting response.

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html) -

> A filter expression is applied after a Query finishes, but before the results are returned. Therefore, a Query consumes the same amount of read capacity, regardless of whether a filter expression is present.

**Note:**
If still looking to do it in DynamoDB query, you need to ensure that `AttributeValue` type provided is correct.

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html) -

> An attribute of type String Set. For example:
> "SS": ["Giraffe", "Hippo" ,"Zebra"]
> Type: Array of strings

So, here change from `new AttributeValue().withS` to `new AttributeValue().withSS` to apply over list. Note that, you will still need to bring your object down to `AttributeValue` granularity which DDB understands.

This [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-expressions.html) has more advanced samples.

Comment: Actually I have `withKeyConditionExpression` but I didn't add here that. I still needs to go through with `FilterExpression` and I need to know how to solve the `contains()` function.

Comment: @AbrahamArnold Can you paste how `String.valueOf(dataList)` looks like ?

Comment: @AbrahamArnold Let us know if this helped :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But did you check this? `nameMap.put("#list", "Data.list");` List is inside Data column as a JSON.

Comment: As can be seen from example pasted above, JSON is not accepted in the query. Did you check this - `"SS": ["Giraffe", "Hippo" ,"Zebra"]` ?

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I will check it let you know. By the way so when I am using `dynamoDBMapper.query()` so it is giving me a list of data. Is it always gives `1MB` of data and do I need to iterate every time to get all the data?

Comment: @AbrahamArnold A single query will at max fetch you 1MB of data. It will load data lazily for you, as and when you go to next element in your list while you are iterating. However, it comes with much higher network cost. In order to get all data at once, you can do - list.size(). It will fetch all the elements at once.

Comment: I am glad I was able to help :) Would highly appreciate accepting and up-voting my answer in that case.

Comment: Thank you very very much for the answer and the clarifications. I got all the things you said. Appreciate putting your time and effort to answer this question. 

Comment: Happy to know that. Much appreciated!